# Merge UV vertex across islands?

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices, faces

I used `Transfer UV Maps` and it generated a UV map that looks good for my mesh in the UV editor, but is actually 100s of small islands that placed together like a big jigsaw puzzle with overlapping/duplicate vertices, which I believe is causing a triangular artifacting in my texture.

I have attached screenshots to hopefully explain what I'm talking about better. When I do `merge UVs by distance` they will not merge across islands. So I'm at a loss of what I can do, any advice or help would be so so so much appreciated.

[image]

I can also put the entire .blender file up if that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all your UVs, hit W and choose Remove Doubles. You can set a threshold distance that should take care of the overlaps. Be careful though, if you have small islands, or large overlaps, it will merge the wrong vertices, so keep the distance as small as possible. Rather do a couple by hand than risking wrongfully merged UVs, because they might be a pain to spot and to fix.

EDIT:
Merging does not work, bc those UV vertices are not doubles. Each triangle seems to be rotated or flipped:
[image]
So adjacent vertices on the UV map are not (necessarily) adjacent in your mesh. I'm afraid that thing is busted beyond repair, meaning there was an issue importing the coordinates. Where did the model come from and wich format was it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but even by hand selecting a group of completely overlapping vertices, choosing Weld and then choosing `Remove Double UVs` the vertices won't merge. It seems like the `Remove Double UVs` doesn't merge a vertex across different UV islands.

Comment: are you allowed to share the .blend?

Comment: Sure! here's a dropbox link to it. Thank you so much for taking a look! https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzknl6lm0r3ua26/start.blend?dl=0

Comment: I used ninjaripper to try to rip it from memory. The other mesh in that file is the base model, this is from the character creation screen so presumably after some scaling/ modifications to various portions of the mesh (but with the same number of vertices/loops). Is there a way I can maybe do the reverse and apply some kind of a mesh transformation to the mesh with the good UVs to make it look like this one with the bad UV?

Comment: Hey! I actually figured out a way to *almost* get it working! I selected my entire mesh and did `Flip/Rotate UVs`, when I flip and rotate the UVs by 1 it gets the texture looking perfect. However, now when I apply a shader (rather than just preview the texture) in Cycles I'm getting some weird (less bad) artifacting. In Eevee or even Cycles when I ctrl-shift-s to directly render the texture it looks fine though. Any clue what might be going on?

Comment: Nevermind! I tried it again and it seemed to work this time !! Thanks for putting me on the right path to figuring out what the heck was going on :)